# Android: Writing to file not working

Tags: java, android, string, append

Can anyone tell me why my code below does not work? I'm trying to append a string to the contents of a text/html file. I just followed the code in the android dev docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

```
package com.example.GetContentThenAppend;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;

public class GetContentThenAppend extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            String FILENAME = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/EngagiaDroid/videos.html";
            String string = "<div style='color: blue; border: thin solid red;'>YO!</div>";

            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
            fos.write(string.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is is the error?  How do you know it is not working?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm receiving a force close message when I run this code...

Comment: Please check out logcat for the error message. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html

Comment: Is there any other way to see the error message. I'm just getting the apk file then test it to my device... I can't see any error, just a force close message...

Comment: Plug your phone into your computer (make sure Debugging is enabled) and type in `adb logcat` into a command prompt window.  Makes sure any emulators are closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your problem in permissions,, have you added write to files permission in your manifest. You can do this by adding this to the manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the `correct permissions` to write to the file.  In your `manifest file`, include this line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have directory EngagiaDroid created. I suggest that you
call

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/EngagiaDroid").mkdirs();
```

before saving file.